# unix_socket path in Heroku?

Tags: mysql, database, heroku, database-connection, unix-socket

I'm trying to configure my database on Heroku.

I have no problem configuring host, database, username, and password, but I have a problem with **unix_socket** parameter.

---

## I have

```
'host'     => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["host"],
'database' => substr(parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["path"], 1),
'username' => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["user"],
'password' => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["pass"],

'unix_socket' => env('UNIX_SOCKET'), <---- **???**
```

**How do we know the path to unix_socket of Heroku ?**

Answer (score 0):

If that is truly an environment variable you can access it on Heroku with `process.env('VAR')`

*(but why on your other envs do you use `getenv()`?)*

It doesn't seem like that's a required setup option though. Do you require the use of the `UNIX_SOCKET` for some reason or are you just trying to match your current local config?

I'm not sure at what level Heroku gives you access to the unix level socket, but some buildpacks make use of it.

nginx: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx